# Chrome extension - javascript error when creating an image with an untrusted source

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my chrome extension, I am scraping some pages, and then later rendering results. I thought it would be nice to include favicons.

It turns out that rendering one of the favicons in my index (haven't tracked it down to one yet) causes this error to bubble up:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://gohugo.io/dist/app.bundle.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I can imagine somebody specifying a js url in their favicon link in their hacked together hugo blog; that part isn't a mystery. And, clearly, I should be filtering out non-images at scraping time. But, I'm confused by the fact that this error can be thrown in the first place. The code I have to render favicons is:

```
            try {
                const resultImg = document.createElement("img");
                resultImg.src = result.favicon;
                if (result.favicon.includes(".js")) {
                    // this never hits
                    console.warn("found favicon that is js!");
                    console.dir(result);
                }
                resultImg.width = 24;
                resultImg.height = 24;
                resultImg.className = "favicon";
                return resultImg
            } catch (err) {
                return document.createElement("span")
            }
```

I'm very sure this is the code that causes the error, since commenting it out, reloading, and redoing the search is error-free, and uncommenting, reloading, and redoing the search always causes the error.

The catch here was a hail-mary, and indeed it is never hit. I probably could attach a load listener of some kind to this element and prevent errors from bubbling up. But what exactly is causing chrome to try and load a script from the src of an image tag?

One possible clue is that when I try to load https://gohugo.io/favicon-32x32.png in Chrome, it actually loads a small html page which shows the image. I don't see the js included in the source of hugo's html, but maybe there is some other favicon url that does have the js bundle in its magic html. Curl on the other hand just downloads a png on that path.

Answer (score 3):

The server for this site is incorrectly adding a `link` header that preloads that js file. It can't run in an extension due to CSP restriction, which is why the error is shown.

The only way to suppress the error is to add a [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) rule to strip the header for requests initiated by the extension:

// manifest.json

```json
  "minimum_chrome_version": "101",
  "permissions": ["declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"],
  "host_permissions": ["*://*.example.com/"],
```

// background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  const RULE = {
    id: 1,
    condition: {
      initiatorDomains: [chrome.runtime.id],
      resourceTypes: ['image'],
    },
    action: {
      type: 'modifyHeaders',
      responseHeaders: [
        {header: 'Link', operation: 'remove'},
      ],
    },
  };
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [RULE.id],
    addRules: [RULE],
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That's gross. Is that a common server misconfiguration? And why does Chrome allow loading js when rendering an image?

Comment: 1) I don't know. 2) https://crbug.com/1449456